# Python 3 support in Google's CoLab

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I have been experimenting with the Jupyter notebooks at https://colab.research.google.com, and it seems that by default they run Python 2.7.

Is there any way to enable Python 3 support on CoLab?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes! Python3 support is now live in Colab.

- When creating a new notebook, there's now an option for Python2 or Python3.
  [image: py3colab]
- For an existing notebook, `Runtime` -> `Change runtime type` will let you switch.

We write the language info into the `kernelspec` in the notebook metadata, so switching runtime type isn't just per-session.

Comment: Is it possible to use an exact version, for example 3.6.4? The default now is 3.6.3.

Comment: Sometimes, especially when uploading a notebook, I am not able to choose the python version when I click "Change Runtime" - the python version doesn't even show up. And syntax highlighting is broken. The cells still run fine, I even have GPU access. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @SamH. any chance you could file a [github issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues) with a link to a misbehaving notebook?

Comment: of course I can't reproduce now. Thanks for the link, will use it if it comes back...