# Can you change kernel in colab notebook?

Tags: python, r, google-colaboratory

I'm just starting out with collaboratory and am wondering if it's possible to switch the kernel? I'd love to jump to a node or R kernel every so often to run something like a web scraper or a regression.

I see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941308/python-3-support-in-googles-colab) that there is no python 3 currently but didn't know if that meant no other kernels at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, not yet. Switching kernel types isn't presently supported.

Answer (score 0):

As of a few months ago, you could use python3 with `Runtime / Change runtime type`